# Adding attachment file name to email link

Tags: attachments, email

I'm doing up a photography site where each post is a photo project, and each post attachment will be displayed on its own attachment page (linked to from the main post page).

On the attachment page, I want to give an email link, below the image.

At the moment, the code is something like this:

`<a href="mailto:me@whatever.com?Subject=Image: <?php the_title(); ?> - [FILE NAME HERE]">Get in touch about this image</a>`

I want the subject of the email to include the *file name* of the attachment (not title, not meta info, not attachment page URL). Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the original attachment filename via [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url):

```
echo basename( wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID ) );
```

or in the form of the example you provided:

```
<a href="mailto:me@whatever.com?Subject=Image: <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo basename( wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID ) ); ?>">Get in touch about this image</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any easy way to get rid of the '.jpg' at the end of the file name?