# Hiding or removing file extension displayed in HTML on attachment page

Tags: attachments

I’m doing up a photography theme in WP at the moment, and I’ve already got great help on [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91547/adding-attachment-file-name-to-email-link) (thanks Milo!) for a previous question.

In that thread, I asked about displaying the file name of an uploaded file on the `attachment.php` page for that file. I’m now using the suggested answer, which uses this code to display the name: `<?php echo basename( wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID ) ); ?>`

What I need to do, however, is to display this file without its extension: so, `filename`, instead of `filename.jpg`. Is there any easy tweak to this existing PHP snippet that could do this? If not, what would be a best-practice way of achieving this end result?

I should add that I’m far from a PHP expert, so take it easy on me... :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

> Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

in combination with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

> Find the numeric position of the last occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

**Example**

```
$name = basename( wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID ) );
echo substr( $name, 0, strrpos( $name, '.' ) );
```

This will show the string (in this case a filename) untill the last occurance of `.`.